# Socket ASP Classic

Tags: sockets, asp-classic, winsock

I'm trying to create a socket with classic asp with the following code

```
Set oSck = Server.CreateObject("MSWinsock.Winsock")
if oSck.state <> 0 then
    oSck.close
end if
oSck.RemoteHost = "192.168.1.101"
oSck.RemotePort = "502"
oSck.Protocol = 0
oSck.connect


myTimer = 0
Do While oSck.State <> 7 and myTimer < 1000000
myTimer = myTimer + 1
Loop


if oSck.State = 7 then
    response.write("connect")
end if
```

but the state never is 7 so the connection is never established. End state is 6.
any ideas? thank you very much

Comment: That's tough ,without knowing what's on the other side. Is is possible to debug the other side, the computer you're connecting to?

Comment: How long does the While loop take to finish? You only increase a counter but do not sleep/delay in the loop.